# how to output different lists to different column? python

Tags: python, csv

I have 3 lists which contain different data:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_2 = [0.1, 0.9, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9]
list_3 = [11, 23, 13, 14, 25]
```

How to output to 3 different columns in CSV (such as `list_1` to column 1, `list_2` to column 2, etc.)?

```
column_1  column_2   column_3
1         0.1        11
2         0.9        23
3         0.6        13
4         0.8        14
5         0.9        25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On doing [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) over the three list, you will get the resultant list as:

```
>>> zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)
[(1, 0.1, 11), (2, 0.9, 23), (3, 0.6, 13), (4, 0.8, 14), (5, 0.9, 25)]
```

Now you may write entire nested list to the CSV file using [`csvwriter.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) as:

```
import csv

zipped_list = zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)
columns = ['column_1', 'column_2', 'columns_3']

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(columns)  # Add column name, single line
    writer.writerows(zipped_list)  # Add nested structure, multi line
```

Content of *output.csv*:

```
column_1,column_2,columns_3
1,0.1,11
2,0.9,23
3,0.6,13
4,0.8,14
5,0.9,25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
list_1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_2=[0.1,0.9,0.6,0.8,0.9]
list_3=[11,23,13,14,25]
with open('you_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(('column_1','column_2' ,'column_3'))
    writer.writerows(zip(list_1, list_2, list_3))
```

out:

```
column_1,column_2,column_3
1,0.1,11
2,0.9,23
3,0.6,13
4,0.8,14
5,0.9,25
```

[image: to make sure i did not copy from anyone, why should i copy such simple code???]

Comment: It doesn't, but who knows. Your original answer was based on the usage of `writer.row()` which you later changed to `writer.rows()`

Comment: i now csv has this method, i want to try it, and i want to make my code clean.

Answer (score 0):

use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) as below and [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) writer with delimiter `\t`

```
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(('column_1','column_2','column_3'))
    for i in zip(list_1,list_2,list_3):
        writer.writerow(i)

# column_1  column_2   column_3
# 1       0.1     11
# 2       0.9     23
# 3       0.6     13
# 4       0.8     14
# 5       0.9     25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (python2):

```
import csv
import sys

list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_2 = [0.1,0.9,0.6,0.8,0.9]
list_3 = [11,23,13,14,25]

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for item  in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3):
        w.writerow(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to do it (using "**zip**()" built-in method):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
list3 = [11,12,13,14,15]
zippedLists = zip(list1, list2, list3)

print("Column_1\tColumn_2\tColumn_3")
for x,y,z in zippedLists:
    print(str(x) + "\t\t" + str(y) + "\t\t" + str(z))
```

Output is:

```
Column_1        Column_2        Column_3
1               6               11
2               7               12
3               8               13
4               9               14
5               10              15
Press any key to continue . . .
```